# How to create ciphers where I assign letters to specific words?

Tags: c#

How to create simple ciphers application in C# where I assign letters to specific words, for example `t` will represent the word `take` so `t` will be the cipher code and `take` will be the description and these ciphers can be stored in database or text file?

I have tried this code below but is does not work for ciphers

```
private void pictureBox5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-EU4PTNQ;Initial Catalog=Medrive;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"))
    {
       con.Open();
              
       if (bunifuTextBox2.Text != "")
       {
           string DescriptionQueryStr = "Select CName from Ciphers";
    
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(DescriptionQueryStr, con))
           {
                        
               string[] tbVals = bunifuTextBox2.Text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
               for (int i = 0; i < tbVals.Length; i++)
               {
                   DescriptionQueryStr = "where Description=@Description" + i.ToString() + "OR";
                   cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description" + i.ToString(), SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbVals[i];
               }
               //Strip off the last OR
               DescriptionQueryStr = DescriptionQueryStr.Substring(0, DescriptionQueryStr.Length - 2);
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

               using (SqlDataReader da = cmd.ExecuteReader())
               {
                   if (da.Read())
                   {
                       var hasAnotherRecord = true;
                       while (hasAnotherRecord)
                       {
                           sb.AppendLine(da.GetValue(0).ToString());
                           hasAnotherRecord = da.Read();
  
                           if (hasAnotherRecord )
                              sb.Append('-');
                        }
                    }
                }
 
                TAbunifuTextBox10.Text = sb.ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Hello via Debug!");
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using C# 2 (this version was released in 2005)? We're currently up to C# 8, although most new projects are on C# 7 still as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding your query conditions (`WHERE ...`) to the actual query, that is sent to the server.

You are constructing your command like

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(DescriptionQueryStr, conn);
```

but you are never altering `cmd.CommandText` (the propery which holds the query that is sent to the sql server) again. So, the query sent to your server is `Select CName from Ciphers` which will return all rows.

In your `for` loop you are altering `DescriptionQueryStr`, but these changes never make it to the `cmd.CommandText`. Furthermore, you are also not handling the conditions right, because instead of appending each new condition to `DescriptionQueryStr`, you are replacing it in every iteration of the loop.

```
//Concat all conditions in a String builder
StringBuilder conditions = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < tbVals.Length; i++) {
    //if there is more than one condition, add an OR inbetween them
    if (i > 0) conditions.Append(" OR ");  
    conditions.Append($"Description = @Description_{i}");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description_{i}", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbVals[i];
}

//If there is at least one parameter, add the conditions to the query
if (tbVals.Length > 0)
    cmd.CommandText += $" WHERE {conditions.ToString()}";
```